# Sublime Text 3 Linter Insatlled But Not Working

Tags: command-line, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I just installed the Sublime JS Linter and double-checked via the Command line to make sure it's installed and it says, it is installed. However, the Sublime JS Linter is not working aka not highlighting anything in my JavaScript sheet. I can't figure out why this. Can you help me out here?

Here is the code in json format that was provided by Sublime via the following process which is shown via this screenshot?

```
{
    "bootstrapped": true,
    "in_process_packages":
    [
    ],
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "Package Control",
        "SublimeLinter-jshint"
    ]
}
```

[image: Sublime Screenshot]

Here is the screenshot that shows the Sublime JS Linter not working (as nothing is highlighted in my JS code)[image: Second Sublime Screnshot]

Comment: Does the Sublime console (`View > Show Console`) say anything? Did you install the `jshint` tool that the linter needs?

Comment: @OdatNurd, no the console doesn't say anything.....and yes I installed the jshint tool per the instructions....it shows too via the screenshot picture that I posted earlier...

`"installed_packages":
 [
  "Package Control",
  "SublimeLinter-jshint"
 ]
`

Comment: `SublimeLinter-jshint` is the package that adds to `SublimeLinter` the ability to run `jshint`; it doesn't include `jshint` itself, you need to install that separately.

Comment: @OdatNurd, how do I install that? Where can I get it from?

Comment: There are some step by step instructions in the README for the jshint linting package: https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint

Comment: OdatNurd, that's exactly what I was using too....but something wasn't working.....going to try it again....